# Masonry: Creating a grid on AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

So I'm pretty familiar with Masonry I'd say, but I haven't had to do this before.

I'm aware of the "appended" method to add items to the grid after page load through ajax, but that's not exactly what I'm trying to do.

My grid structure doesn't exist at all until it's called via ajax.

For example (pseudocode):

1. Page Loads
2. User Clicks a Link
3. AJAX call, HTML string is returned and added to the dom via jQuery.
4. Need to instantiate the masonry grid based on this HTML.

Basically the HTML that is returned via AJAX looks something like this:

```
<div class="grid-57">
    <a class="item" href="http://www.example.com">
        <img src="http://fpoimg.com/350x350"/></a> 
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="http://www.example.com">
        <img src="http://fpoimg.com/350x250"/></a> 
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="http://www.example.com">
        <img src="http://fpoimg.com/350x450"/></a> 
    </a>
</div>
```

So as you can see I'm not adding to an existing grid or masonry, I need to create a new one on successful return of the AJAX.

My JS looks something like this:

```
$('.get-grid').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.post(ajaxurl, { action: 'get_grid', id: id  }, function(response) {

        // Append this html to the area of the site where I have the grids. 
        $('.all-the-grids').append(response);

        // Here is where i need to actually turn this HTML that I just added into a masonry object and lay it out.
        var $container = $('.grid-' + id);
        msnry = new Masonry( $container[0], {
            columnWidth: 188,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            gutter: 10
        }); 
        msnry.on('layoutComplete', function(){
            // never making it in here.
        }); 
    });
});
```

Any idea how to do this?

**EDIT**

It appears my grid is getting laid out correctly, no errors, but it's never reaching the layoutComplete callback here.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way as you would usually with Masonry, the fact that you're doing it in a callback doesn't really change anything.

```
$('.get-grid').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.post(ajaxurl, { action: 'get_grid', id: id  }, function(response) {

        // Append this html to the area of the site where I have the grids. 
        var grids = $('.all-the-grids');
        grids.append(response);
        var msnry = new Masonry(grids[0], {
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, but I don't think it's working. I'm trying to call `.on('layoutComplete')` to know when it's done loading and it never makes it there.

Comment: It appears my grid is getting laid out, no errors there, it's just never reaching the layoutComplete I guess is what appears to be my issue.

Comment: Is it possible the event has simply already triggered by the time you're listening to it? Events aren't promises, attaching too late won't let you know it's already triggered.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Images in Layout, first thing you have to do is wait till all images loaded in that element and then instantiate. Try below code

```
$containers = $('.all-the-grids');
$containers.append(response).imagesLoaded(function() { 
   $containers.masonry({
      itemSelector: '. a'
   }); 
});
```

Note: `imagesLoaded` is a jQuery plugin

Comment: This isn't the issue.